# Limiting the number of queries returns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my query

```
SELECT Fullname, rank, id_no, TIN, birthdate, 
hair, eyes, Blood, height, weight, marks, name, address
FROM  [******_DOMAIN\****_*****].*******view
```

Problem is, source table has too many duplicates, how do I my limit query to the latest row on the database?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks In advance

My next problem is that the view shows me a `birthdate` string format of `yyyymmdd`, I need to change it to `mm/dd/yyyy` can please provide me a function? using the same string above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For duplicates, you can limit the records by using `SELECT DISTINCT`, and to only retrieve a certain amount of records, you can use `SELECT TOP #` where # is the amount of records. As for latest record- I'm not sure it can be done unless you have a date field on the record of when it was inserted.

Comment: i have a field on the original dbase named sysdate, would that be enough to narrow the query time?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TOP` for limiting the records and `ORDER BY` to sort the records based on your desired column.

example.

```
SELECT    TOP 5 Fullname, rank, id_no, 
          TIN, birthdate, hair, eyes, 
          Blood, height, weight, marks, name, address 
FROM      viewName
ORDER BY  yourDesiredClumn desc
```

this will display only 5 records.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

Select TOP(#) Fullname, rank, id_no, TIN, birthdate, hair, eyes, ....